# Throw error on null value in spark column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala function that takes in a data frame and adds an additional "id" column to it. The generated id is a GUID derived from the values of other columns in the data frame.

```
  def addDeterministicID(colName: String, colNames: String*)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val allColNames = colNames :+ colName
    // get columns with the given names from the data frame
    val cols: Seq[Column] = allColNames.sorted.map(name => df.col(name))
    // return data frame with a new id (uuid) column from hashed values
    df.withColumn("id", toUUID(hash(cols: _*)))
  }
```

If there is a null value in any of the columns I use to generate the id from, I need to throw an exception. How can i best do this?

The `toUUID` function is a simple UDF using the Java `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes` to generate the final ID and `hash` is the built-in one from Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the total number of columns containing nulls:

```
val null_cols = df.select(
    allColNames.map(x => max(isnull(col(x)).cast("int"))).reduce((x, y) => x + y)
).collect()(0)(0)
```

and then you can throw an exception if `null_cols > 0`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Two questions. Can I not use the cols: Seq[Column] directly to do this? Also, can you explain the logic behind the int cast?

Comment: You can use df.columns instead of allColNames. The int casts the isnull boolean to an integer (0/1) and get the maximum. if there is a null in the column, the maximum for that column will be 1.